# SQL mapping from 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables that look like this:

Tabel 1 :

```
ID      NAME
1       car1
2       car2
3       car3
4       car4
```

Tabel 2 :

```
car_id      liter
2           100
2           300
3           400
1           500
3           600
```

I want to output something like:

Tabel 3:

```
car_id      liters
car2        100 
car2        300
car3        400
car1        500
car3        600
```

I try to write something like:

```
SELECT tabel2.car_id
     , tabel1.ID 
  FROM tabel2
     , tabel2 
 INNER 
  JOIN tabel3  
    ON tabel2.car_id = tabel1.ID;
```

I know this is kinda a newbie question, but I'm new to SQL.

Comment: Have a read of a basic tutorial or something

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the two tables:

```
select t1.name, t2.liter
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.car_id
order by t2.liter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the desired result:

```
select t1.NAME, t2.liter
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.id=t2.car_id
ORDER BY t2.liter DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.name, t2.liter from table1 t1 ,table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.car_id 
order by t2.liter;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select t1.name, t2.liter
  from table1 t1 ,
       table2 t2
 here t1.id = t2.car_id ;
```